# How to use Live Agent Automated Invitation with Custom Variables?

Tags: servicecloud, liveagent

On the automated invitation configuration page for Live Agent, there is an option to use a custom variable to trigger the invitation but I don't see any documentation on how is it supposed to be used. Anyone with experience on that?. Ideally I would like to reference there a javascript variable.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found my answer in the Live Agent developer guide.

In the deployment code we need to use this method:

```
liveagent.setCustomVariable('mycustomvariable', 'somevalue');
```