# How does setcustomvariable() work?

Tags: javascript, api

I am currently setting up Live Agent and want to trigger the automatic chat pop-up using custom variables stored in the websites source code. I wanted to ask if someone could explain to me how the setcustomvariable() deployment API works, possibly with an example? Please don't just send me the link to the developer's site as it does not clearly explain how to use the code....

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

[How to use Live Agent Automated Invitation with Custom Variables?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32414/how-to-use-live-agent-automated-invitation-with-custom-variables)

You call this method inside the same script that initializes live agent.